# Square root of prime is irrational. Is this a valid proof?

Tags: prime-numbers, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

I know similar questions exist, but I want to know, if this is a valid proof.

A prime number has 1 and it self as divisors. So the subset of a prime number is $ D(p) = \{1, p\}$

Now I want to prove $\sqrt{p} = \frac{a}{b}$  , to get the opposite.

Also $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Let's square it.

$p = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$

And divide by $b^2$

$\frac{p}{b^2} = \frac{a^2}{b^4}$

In this case ${b^2}$ is also a divisor of  $p$, which doesn't fit the definition of prime numbers. So the square root of a prime number must be irrational.

Comment: I can't follow this.  How do you know that $\frac {a^2}{b^4}$ is an integer?

Comment: @lulu a and b are natural numbers.

Comment: Ok.  But that doesn't explain why you think $\frac {a^2}{b^4}$ is an integer.

Comment: The number of prime divisors of $a^2$ and $b^2$ are even. Now the number of prime divisors of $pb^2$ is odd hence it can't be equal to $a^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not correct, there are some issues.

Suppose you have $a$ and $b$, two *integers*. We say that $b$ is a divisor of $a$ if there is some *integer* $x$ such that $a = bx$. Now, according to this definition, a prime number $p$ is a *positive* integer that has exactly two positive divisors, namely, $1$ and $p$.

So, in your proof, when you say

> $$\frac{p}{b^2} = \frac{a^2}{b^4} \,.$$ In this case $b^2$ is a divisor of $p$ which doesn't fit the definition of prime number.

this is false. To say that $b^2$ is a divisor of $p$, there must be some *integer* $x$ such that $p = b^2x$, and this is not the case, since we cannot factor $b^2$ of $a^2/b^2$ to get another integer.

You see? I hope this doesn't confuse you more.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $ p$ is a prime $\ge 2$ and

$$\sqrt{p}=\frac ab$$
with

$0<b<a$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$.

then

$$a^2=pb^2$$

$$\implies a|pb^2$$
and by Gauss,

$$a|p$$

thus
$$a=1 \text{ or } a=p$$

$ a$ cannot be equal to $1$ because
$0<b<a$.

If $ a= p$ then $p^2=pb^2$ gives $p=b^2$

this is in contradiction with the fact that $ p $ is prime.

Comment: This seems like more than a hint :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You read it?

Comment: @Clayton Thanks. i took it off.

Comment: @Azif00 His answer is not valid.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Why not?

Comment: @Azif00 Did you Read the answer above mine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, how do you know $\frac{a^2}{b^4} \in \mathbb{Z}$? Here are two ideas once you get $p = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$. Consider that $b|a$ even though you wrote $\frac{a}{b}$ in lowest terms. Or, consider the parity of the amount of primes on each side of the equation
$$b^2p=a^2$$
Either will help you prove what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you think about my current proof?

Comment: You need to prove that $\frac{a^2}{b^4}$ is an integer, which you assume when saying $b^2|p$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\sqrt{p}=\dfrac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ being relatively prime integers. Thus, $p=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$ and so $a^2=p\cdot b^2$.

$a^2$ must be divisible by $p$ because $p, a^2,$ and $b^2$ are all integers and so $a$ must be divisible by $p$ as well. If we define $a=pc$ where $c$ is also an integer, then $p=\dfrac{p^2\cdot c^2}{b^2} \rightarrow 1 = \dfrac{p\cdot c^2}{b^2} \rightarrow b^2 = p \cdot c^2$.

$b^2$ must also be divisible by $p$ because $p, b^2,$ and $c^2$ are all integers and so $b$ must be divisible by $p$ as well. However, $a$ and $b$ were defined to be relatively prime and yet they have a common factor of $p$, which means that they are not relatively prime.

Thus, the claim that $\sqrt{p}$ can be written as the division of two relatively prime integers $a$ and $b$ is contradicted as $a$ and $b$ cannot be relatively prime.